# R: Adding two dataframes (different number of rows)

Tags: r

I have one dataframe (df1):

```
Type     CA     AR     Total
alpha    2      3        5
beta     1      5        6
gamma    6      2        8
delta    8      1        9
```

I have another dataframe (df2)

```
Type     CA     AR     Total
alpha    3      4        7
beta     2      6        8
delta    4      1        5
```

How can I add the above two data frames to get the following output:

```
Type     CA     AR     Total
alpha    5      7        12
beta     3      11       14
gamma    6      2        8
delta    12     2        14
```

If I use a code along this line:

```
new_df = df1 + df2
```

I get the following error:

```
‘+’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

How do I add the two dataframes, perhaps by matching the names under the "type" column?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: `df1[df1$Type %in% df2$Type, ] + df2[df2$Type %in% df1$Type, ]` is halfway there. Then consider an rbind.

Comment: Also your columns don't match -- is that a problem?

Comment: Assuming you want to add CA values to CA values (which doesn't appear to be the case in your desired output but i'm not sure if that's a mistake or not), then the answer I gave to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30539527/r-add-two-dataframes-same-dimension-different-order-column) will work with unequal numbers of rows.

Answer (score 1):

(Slightly out-of-order rows due to `aggregate()`'s behavior of ordering the output by the grouping column, but correct data.)

```
df1 <- data.frame(Type=c('alpha','beta', 'gamma','delta'), CA=c(2,1,6,8), AR=c(3,5,2,1), Total=c(5,6,8,9) );
df2 <- data.frame(Type=c('alpha','beta','delta'), AR=c(3,2,4), CA=c(4,6,1), Total=c(7,8,5) );
aggregate(.~Type,rbind(df1,setNames(df2,names(df1))),sum);
##    Type CA AR Total
## 1 alpha  5  7    12
## 2  beta  3 11    14
## 3 delta 12  2    14
## 4 gamma  6  2     8
```

Answer (score 0):

library(dplyr)

```
rbind(df1,df2)%>%group_by(Type)%>%summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

Comment: This does not produce the output given by the OP